# Black screen on Nvidia HDMI on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: drivers, gnome, nvidia, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 64-bits kernel `3.19.0-15-generic` on a Dell Vostro 3460 with Intel + Nvidia card. I have installed the `nvidia-349` drivers from `xorg-edgers` ppa. Everything is working fine, nvidia-prime and all, but when I plug my HDMI monitor to the laptop, the screen goes black instantly, and nothing changes until I'll unplug it.

I've installed the nvidia drivers from the ppa because this problem was already happening with the default proprietary graphic drivers.

Previously I had installed Linux Mint 17.1 with the same drivers and everything working fine.

What can I do to solve this problem? Can this be a Gnome Shell specific problem, or is it a system issue?

Comment: Linux Mint 17 is based on Ubuntu 14.04 and everything is working fine with the same drivers. 15.04 hasn't been officially released yet, so there could be a bug in the 15.04 beta.

Comment: It seems to be a bug on GNOME Shell. I installed the Cinnamon desktop environment and it's able to switch to the HDMI monitor with no _(extra)_ problems _(other than the ones it already had on Linux Mint 17.1)_. I also added the GNOME 3 Team PPA to the system, but they still don't have `vivd` repositories. I'll be using cinnamon While this bug isn't fixed.

Comment: My mistake, the PPA already contains `vivid` repositories, as filtered here  https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3?field.series_filter=vivid anyway it seems this bug is not fixed, maybe even not reported yet. I shall search for it and report if not found.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now (1 month after the question). I can even extend my desktop, but it requires a restart in GNOME (`Alt + F2, r, enter`) every time I open my laptop lid and activate the secondary screen. Not a huge problem.